# Update pySpark Dataframe Schema

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, schema

I have a pyspark data frame with below schema;

```
{'type': 'struct',
 'fields': [{'name': 'from', 'type': 'long', 'nullable': True, 'metadata': {}},
  {'name': 'to', 'type': 'long', 'nullable': True, 'metadata': {}},
  {'name': 'weight', 'type': 'double', 'nullable': True, 'metadata': {}}]}
```

I would need to update the schema as follows;

```
{'type': 'struct',
 'fields': [{'name': 'from',
   'type': 'long',
   'nullable': True,
   'metadata': {'HIVE_TYPE_STRING': 'bigint'}},
  {'name': 'to',
   'type': 'long',
   'nullable': True,
   'metadata': {'HIVE_TYPE_STRING': 'bigint'}},
  {'name': 'weight',
   'type': 'double',
   'nullable': True,
   'metadata': {'HIVE_TYPE_STRING': 'double'}}]}
```

Appreciate if anyone could help

I tried to convert schema by using pandas dataframe, but would need to update the pyspark schema directly without converting it into pandas dataframe

Comment: Please elaborate your use case in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**With Spark 3.3 up**

I think you would like to change a metadata field within Dataframe.

To do that there is a method called `withMetadata`. Here's a documentation link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withMetadata.html

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "John"), (2, "Jane")], ["id", "name"])
df = df.withMetadata("id", {"HIVE_TYPE_STRING": "bigint"})
df = df.withMetadata("name", {"HIVE_TYPE_STRING": "varchar"})
```

Result is:

```
{"fields":[{"metadata":{"HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"bigint"},"name":"id","nullable":true,"type":"long"},{"metadata":{"HIVE_TYPE_STRING":"varchar"},"name":"name","nullable":true,"type":"string"}],"type":"struct"}
```